# Unable to mock BufferedWriter class in junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I am using a BufferedWriter object in my source code

```
BufferedWriter outputToErrorFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
outputToErrorFile.append("some string");
```

I am trying to mock it in my test case as follows:

```
BufferedWriter mockBufferedWriter = PowerMockito.mock(BufferedWriter.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedWriter.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockBufferedWriter);
PowerMockito.when(mockBufferedWriter.append(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenThrow(new IOException());
```

However, the BufferedWriter does not get mocked and it always goes into the actual implementation. Is it because that one cannot mock BufferedWriter as it is a concrete class? Does that mean none of the java.io classes can be mocked? Is there a way to mock it, or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: `BufferedWriter` is not `final`, so you need not use PowerMockito, "plain old" mockito is enough; try and `doThrow(exception).when(writer).append(anyString())`

Comment: Not as familiar with PowerMock, but how are you running your tests?  Do you need to have `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`?

Comment: @MikeKobit Yes I have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock Java IO classes (including their constructors, so future instances also get mocked) with the JMockit library, though you will likely face difficulties such as a `NullPointerException` from the `Writer()` constructor (depending on how the mocking was done, and which IO classes were mocked).

However, note that the Java IO API contains many interacting classes and deep inheritance hierarchies. In your example, the `FileWriter` class would also probably need to be mocked, otherwise an actual file would get created.

Also, usage of IO classes in application code is usually just an implementation detail, which can easily be changed. You could switch from IO streams to writers, from regular IO to NIO, or use the new Java 8 utilities, for example. Or use a 3rd-party IO library.

Bottom line, it's just a terribly bad idea to try and mock IO classes. It's even worse if (as suggested in another answer) you change the client code to have `Writer`s, etc. *injected* into the SUT. Dependency injection is just not for this kind of thing.

Instead, use *real* files in the local file system, preferably from a test directory which can be deleted after the test, and/or use fixed resource files when only reading. Local files are fast and reliable, and lead to more useful tests. Certain developers will say that "a test is not a unit test if it touches the file system", but that's just dogmatic advice.

Comment: Can you explain why it is a bad idea to inject Writers into the SUT ? My idea would be to write a custom class, which creates a BufferedWriter or any writer I need and makes this writer accessible via a public interface. Then I want to inject this custom class into my application class. Doing that enables me to change the implementation of the writer any time, without changing the business logic, as I simply inject this writer into the class containing the business logic. What's bad about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use plain mockito. Since `BufferedWriter` is not final, there's no need to use PowerMockito here.

With plain mockito, you can just write:

```
final BufferedWriter writer = mock(BufferedWriter.class);
final IOException exception = new IOException();

doThrow(exception).when(writer).append(anyString());
```

Of course, you'll have a problem if your `BufferedWriter` is initialized within your method itself, and you have no method to return it for a given file (and by the way, you should use `Files.newBufferedWriter()` and a `Path`).

Devising a real solution, however, requires that you show the code you are testing.

Comment: Can't it mocked by Mockito or PowerMockito? You are right that it is not final and PowerMockito may not be used. However, I guess you may use it for normal methods also.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mock `BufferedWritter` at all. Create a writer backed by a `ByteArrayOutputStream` in your test, pass it to the class you are testing, then inspect it when you are done. This may require refactoring your code to create a seam for testing. Here's one possible implementation:

```
public void writeToWriter(Writer writer) {
  writer.append("some string");
}
```

Then your test can look like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, charset);

objectUnderTest.writeToWriter(writer);

String actualResult = writer.toString(charset);
assertEquals("some string", actualResult);
```

If the method you are testing needs to open and close the stream,  I'm fond of using Guava's `CharSink` class:

```
public void writeToSink(CharSink sink) {
  try (Writer writer = sink.openBufferedStream()) {
    writer.append("some string");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest not mocking the BufferedWriter class?

Comment: @AbhishekChauhan two reasons: 1) mocking is best when you need to make assertions about the interaction, but in this case you don't care about the exact interaction (is the code under test making one call to append() or two?), and 2) it can be problematic to mock classes that you don't control (because when setting the expectations you are hard-coding what the behavior is). The one case where I might mock a writer is if I was testing a case where any interaction with the writer throws an exception (though even then, are you sure you know when the exception would be thrown?)

Comment: I agree with your point. I am just curious to know whether the BufferedWriter class is allowed to be mocked or not, because I tried many ways to mock it and have failed to do so. Is it not possible to mock it?

Comment: @AbhishekChauhan yes, you can mock BufferedWriter. Just follow fge's suggestion, and pass the mock writer into the method/object being tested.