# mocking file.bufferedReader() gives NullPointerException

Tags: kotlin, mockito, tdd, bufferedreader

Why `file.bufferedReader()` is giving me `NullPointerException` here?

```
val file = mock<File>()
when(file.bufferedReader()).thenThrow(IOException::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread [Unable to mock BufferedWriter class in junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915552/unable-to-mock-bufferedwriter-class-in-junit)

> You can mock Java IO classes (including their constructors, so future
>   instances also get mocked) with the JMockit library, though you will
>   likely face difficulties such as a NullPointerException from the
>   Writer() constructor (depending on how the mocking was done, and which
>   IO classes were mocked).
>
> However, note that the Java IO API contains many interacting classes
>   and deep inheritance hierarchies. In your example, the FileWriter
>   class would also probably need to be mocked, otherwise an actual file
>   would get created.
>
> Also, usage of IO classes in application code is usually just an
>   implementation detail, which can easily be changed. You could switch
>   from IO streams to writers, from regular IO to NIO, or use the new
>   Java 8 utilities, for example. Or use a 3rd-party IO library.
>
> Bottom line, it's just a terribly bad idea to try and mock IO classes.
>   It's even worse if (as suggested in another answer) you change the
>   client code to have Writers, etc. injected into the SUT. Dependency
>   injection is just not for this kind of thing.
>
> Instead, use real files in the local file system, preferably from a
>   test directory which can be deleted after the test, and/or use fixed
>   resource files when only reading. Local files are fast and reliable,
>   and lead to more useful tests. Certain developers will say that "a
>   test is not a unit test if it touches the file system", but that's
>   just dogmatic advice.