# Testing private methods in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tdd, private

How to test private methods in Kotlin? I tried to add `@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)` from `androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting` but it doesn’t make my function private

This is how I’m using it

```
@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
fun doSomething() {}
```

[EDIT]

I understand that I shouldn't test `private` methods, but it's now always trivial. What about below case.

I have a CsvReader class

```
class CsvReader(private val inputStream: InputStream, private val separator: String = "\t") {
    fun read(): List<String> {
        return read(inputStream.bufferedReader())
    }
    private fun read(bufferedReader: BufferedReader): List<String> {
        val line = bufferedReader.use { it.readLine() } // `use` is like try-with-resources in Java
        return parse(line)
    }
    private fun parse(line: String): List<String> {
        return line.split(separator)
    }
}
```

And I wrote tests for it

```
class CsvReaderTest {
    private val stream = mock<InputStream>()
    private val reader = CsvReader(stream)
    private val bufferedReader = mock<BufferedReader>()
    @Test
    fun read() {
        whenever(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("Jakub\tSzwiec")
        reader.read(bufferedReader) shouldEqual listOf("Jakub", "Szwiec")
    }
    @Test
    fun readWhenEmpty() {
        whenever(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("")
        reader.read(bufferedReader) shouldEqual listOf("")
    }
    @Test
    fun throwIOExceptionWhenReadingProblems() {
        whenever(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenThrow(IOException::class.java)
        val read = { reader.read(bufferedReader) }
        read shouldThrow IOException::class
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, for tests I need to call private function `fun read(bufferedReader: BufferedReader): List<String>` because when mocking `File`, `file.bufferedReader` gives `NullPointerException` [Unable to mock BufferedWriter class in junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915552/unable-to-mock-bufferedwriter-class-in-junit)

Comment: An annotation cannot make a function be private. It can help Android Studio warn you about using that function from things other than test code, but that's about it.

Comment: You can't directly test private methods, and you can't make a method private any other way than the keyword `private`.  Either make them `internal` or only test public API.

Comment: Testing a private function is a really bad practice. Always test the public api; don't tie your test to implementations details.

Comment: For the record: splitting by "," is like 5% of what a CSV parser does for you. Seriously: don't do such things. Use an existing robust CSV parser library. You invent the wheel, and you will repeat all the mistakes that people run into when doing that. Believe me, I have been there to. Parsing *arbitrary* CSV correctly is **hard**.

Comment: I know @GhostCat. That's the interview assignment :)

Comment: OK, that makes sense then ;-) ... and my answer for sure doesn't prevent other folks from coming by and answering on the technical side of things!

Comment: did you try the mockk lib? it is able to test private methods

Answer (score 14):

You can use java reflections:

To test the method:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
      private fun printGreetings(name: String): String {
        return "Hello, $name"
      }
}
```

That's enough:

```
  private val classUnderTest = spyk(ClassUnderTest()) 

  @Test
    fun `should return greetings`() {
      val method = classUnderTest.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("printGreetings", String::class.java)
      method.isAccessible = true
      val parameters = arrayOfNulls<Any>(1)
      parameters[0] = "Piotr"

      assertEquals("Hello, Piotr", method.invoke(classUnderTest, *parameters) )
  }
```

Comment: What is `spyk` here?

Comment: FYI: Works without `spyk`

Comment: spyk is coming from MockK testing library , see this https://mockk.io/#spy

Comment: @mmccabe, in my case it works for `spyk`. If I set `classUnderTest = mockk<ClassUnderTest>(relaxed = true)`, then `method.invoke` returns `""`. If you want to call the method without returning a result, it would be enough.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. "Failed to create proxy for com.test.ClassUnderTest. Class is final."

Answer (score 8):

like this:

```kotlin
fun callPrivate(objectInstance: Any, methodName: String, vararg args: Any?): Any? {
        val privateMethod: KFunction<*>? =
            objectInstance::class.functions.find { t -> return@find t.name == methodName }

        val argList = args.toMutableList()
        (argList as ArrayList).add(0, objectInstance)
        val argArr = argList.toArray()

        privateMethod?.apply {
            isAccessible = true
            return call(*argArr)
        }
            ?: throw NoSuchMethodException("Method $methodName does not exist in ${objectInstance::class.qualifiedName}")
        return null
    }
```

you need to pass instance of the object you want the method to be called on, method name and required arguments

Comment: This is actually very cool, if you really really really have to test `private` functions, or to learn more about Kotlin reflection. Generally, though, it's advised to use the adequate visibility modifier `internal` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 1):

There is only **one** answer to this: don't even try to test the private methods *directly*.

You write source code to communicate **intent**. If you make something `private` then that something is an internal implementation detail. It is subject to change the very next second.

Meaning: of course you want to ensure that your private methods are executed during your unit tests, but you want them to be invoked by your "public interfaces".

If you really have a lot of private methods that are somehow decoupled from your "public interface", then you might want to put the corresponding functionality in its own class, that defines its own "public".

Comment: what if you still want to test that this private function works correctly?

Comment: it is subject to change, but I still want it to behave properly

Comment: Then you should test the usage paths that lead to that private detail.

Comment: The does not answer the question, OP was not asking whether or not it is a good idea to test private methods, but rather how to do so.

Comment: @Attila There are always other people that give the "technical" answer to such questions. But remember: content here is not only written for the OP asking the question, but for all future readers. And thing is: it is a **bad** idea to test private methods. But unfortunately: a lot of people do **not understand** that part. You can write your own answer, and explain to people how to correctly shot themselves into their feet. I prefer to tell them: avoid shooting yourself in the foot, because that is a bad thing to do. What is more helpful in the end, the readers can decide themselves.

Comment: And just to be really clear: I am not saying that you shouldnt test for the functionality that private methods implement. But the correct place would be to have decent unit tests for the public interface and ensure that those tests lead to "full" coverage of your production code. But making the private methods themselves the "target" of a distinct test is simply a bad idea. Doing so means creating bad designs, and spending time in places where it should not be spent.

Comment: @GhostCat, I appreciate the rational behind your answer, it does make sense indeed and brings added value. However, shouldn't be your "non technical/direct" answer added as a comment only to the OP question rather than a proper answer to the question then?

Comment: @Attila By definition, comments on this site are volatile. There is no guarantee that someone doesn't flag them (no longer needed, or some other reason) ... and then some moderator deletes the comment. So, whenever I want to say something I consider "worthy to last", I am using an answer over comments.

Comment: I think these are multiple discussions. Testing on a higher level (e.g. the interface) is important, and exhaustively verifying code-paths and complexity can be important. Testing nitty-gritty implementation details will probably lead to a less flexible system and brittle tests. Only testing the public interface will probably lead to a system that adapts better to change, but probably result in more unexpected behaviour on edge-cases, since you didn't exhaustively test all branches.

This "never test the details"-attitude, in my opinion, borders on dogma, and does not address the question.

Comment: I generally agree: but the point would be to test the public contract of your public API. There is still some middle ground, like: have some "internal" "utility" class that has an "internal" interface that is more low level, and of course, you could then test against that stuff.

Comment: This is fundamentally incorrect for unit testing, and is only partially true for systems testing. The space shuttle engineers verified the booster rockets fired and got the thing off the ground, but the O-rings were hidden inside the construction and they couldn't see the potential failure. The point of unit testing is to verify correct operation under a range of circumstances. That includes verifying computations that aren't exposed to the end user through the class design.

Comment: @BrettonWade But it doesn't help you one bit to test that private method **by itself**. In the end, that private method is somehow used by other code. You want that the public entry points to your code give the results you *know* to come out of that private code. It doesn't help you one bit if you only test the private methods, but your public facing methods use them in some *other* way.

Comment: @GhostCat As example of a case where public API yield the right answer, but the internal private methods failed: A factory class that creates objects by some trait (say Colors), and caches the result. If it hasn't yielded a particular color yet, it creates a new one, adds it to the cache, and returns it. The public API might properly yield a requested color every time you ask, but the internal API has a bug where the cache name got an extra character added, so the cache always fails, and you get an unexpected memory leak.

Comment: @GhostCat you say, "by itself." Sure - you have to test the public API *as well*, But your original post was "there is only one answer, don't even try (to test the private methods)"

Comment: @BrettonWade Fair enough, I reworded the answer a bit.